# IDispatch GetIDsOfNames в Delphi

Tags: delphi, 1с, com

Имеется код для подключения к базе **1С-предприятие 8.3** и выполнения в ней функции Тест1(5, 2).

```
var
  pDisp : IDispatch;
  sMethodName : Widestring;
  iDispId : TDispId;
  dpPutArgs : TDispParams;
  ei : TExcepInfo;
  iError : uint;
  vSet : olevariant;
  vParams : array [1..63] of olevariant;
  VarResult : OleVariant;
  function_1c : AnsiString;

begin
  pDisp := CreateOleObject('V83.Application');
  sMethodName := 'Connect';
  OleCheck (pDisp.GetIDsOfNames (GUID_NULL, @sMethodName, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, @iDispId));
  vSet := 'File=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\InfoBase';
  FillChar (dpPutArgs, sizeof (dpPutArgs), 0);
  dpPutArgs.rgvarg := @vSet;
  dpPutArgs.cArgs := 1;
  dpPutArgs.cNamedArgs := 0;
  dpPutArgs.rgdispidNamedArgs := nil;
  OleCheck (pDisp.Invoke (iDispId, GUID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,
DISPATCH_METHOD, dpPutArgs, @VarResult, @ei, @iError));

  function_1c := 'Тест1';
  sMethodName := function_1c;
  OleCheck (pDisp.GetIDsOfNames (GUID_NULL, @sMethodName, 1, GetThreadLocale, @iDispId));

  vParams[1] := 2;
  vParams[2] := 5;

  FillChar (dpPutArgs, sizeof (dpPutArgs), 0);
  dpPutArgs.rgvarg := @vParams;
  dpPutArgs.cArgs := 2;
  dpPutArgs.cNamedArgs := 0;
  dpPutArgs.rgdispidNamedArgs := nil;
  OleCheck (pDisp.Invoke (iDispId, GUID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,
DISPATCH_METHOD, dpPutArgs, @VarResult, @ei, @iError));
  pDisp := UnAssigned;
end;
```

Проблема заключается в том, что необходимо вместо V83.Application использовать **V83.COMConnector**. Если просто изменить одну строчку кода, то, при попытке получить идентификатор функции на втором GetIdsOfNames, программа сообщает об **ошибке "Неизвестное имя"**. Пробовал вводить английское имя функции (Test), ошибка оставалась.

Склоняюсь думать, что GetidsOfNames не понимает кодировку строки "Тест1". Даже при V83.Application приходиться использовать костыль в виде преобразования AnsiString в WideString перед получением идентификатора (`SMethodName := function_1c`).

Также я пробовал, вместо позднего связывания, чётко прописать в коде функцию на  выполнение, а потом смотрел какие системные интерфейсы дёргаются при таком варианте. Всё сходится, как и в коде выше: сначала GetidsOfNames, а потом Invoke.

```
  OLE_obj := CreateOleObject('V83.COMConnector');
  OLE_obj := OLE_obj.Connect('File=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\InfoBase');
  ansver := OLE_obj.Тест1(2, 5);
```

P.S. Использую Delphi-XE3, 1С-Предприятие 8.3. В базе данная функция находиться в глобальном общем модуле, выставлены все галочки для клиент-серверного взаимодействия, сама функция Тест1 является экспортируемой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка заключается не в кодировках имён методов, а в **IDispatch** интерфейсах.

Дело в том, что вызов первого **Invoke** (для функции Connect) **не изменяет** значение самого IDispatch интерфейса (pDisp). То есть при попытке обратиться к функции "Тест1" мы никак не получим её ID, т.к. pDisp ссылается на V83.COMConnector, а не на саму базу данных.

Метод Connect для 1С базы данных возвращает "ссылку на базу данных". Следовательно, надо в pDisp записать полученную ссылку.

```
  OleCheck (pDisp.Invoke (iDispId, GUID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, dpPutArgs, @VarResult, @ei, @iError));
  pDisp := VarResult;
```

После этого можно спокойно обращаться к функциям/процедурам 1С базы.

Comment: Крайне странно, что при V83.Application мы могли получить доступ к базе после Connect, не изменяя pDisp вручную.